# remove type text from input field

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

Note: I am new to Javascript.

Here is code:

it is from the html page itself

```
<form action="#" id="ToolKeywordSearch">
  <input type="text" class="ProductFinderText"
          id="ToolSearchField"onblur="if(this.value=='')    
             {this.value='Enter Search Term ';}" 
                onclick="if (this.value == 'Enter Search Term ')
                  { this.value = ''; }" value="Enter Search Term " />
</form>

 ___________________________________
|  _____________________     ______ |      (restriction does not let me insert image)
| |                  |O |   |      ||
| |enter search term | \|   |Search||                      
|  ---------------------     ------ |
|___________________________________|
```

Here what it does: when search button is pressed it opens the search field

the search image is a background:

```
#ToolSearchField {

 background:url(../../Content/images/search_but.png) no-repeat scroll 
    right center   transparent;
```

cursor:pointer;
    }

How to remove the text in the search field? with Javascript or CSS, tried both but it wasn't successful.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jo = document.getElementById("ToolSearchField").value;
    alert(jo);
</script>

I receive Enter Search Term as an output. 

Then if I insert remove(); instead, it doesn't do anything.

var jo = document.getElementById("ToolSearchField").value;
    jo.remove();
```

The final result should have search button that launches the search action.

Tell me please, what am I doing wrong.

Comment: great suggestions, although I needed this sort of answer:

     [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6364092/1786058)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The var `jo` you're instantiating has the string value "Enter Search Term " after your first line of javascript. In the next line you're telling this string to `remove()`, which isn't achieving anything in the original element.

Try `document.getElementById("ToolSearchField").value = "";` instead!

Comment: how to go about to remove onblur()?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you really want a placeholder:

```
<input type="text" class="ProductFinderText"
    id="ToolSearchField"
    placeholder="Enter Search Term " />
```

Then include a [placeholder polyfill for older browsers.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=placeholder%20polyfill&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial here: http://www.ozzu.com/javascript-tutorials/tutorial-watermark-text-boxes-html-javascript-jquery-t106384.html

The tutorial shows how to achieve your effect using jQuery. If you are new to Javascript, then I strongly advise investigating jQuery, it makes a lot of things a lot easier.